# MS Access VBA run query

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to extract the `Member.HomeEmail` and store it in `strEmail`, and if more mail address are found separate them using `;` like
`1@mail.com; 2@mail.com; 3@mail.com`, so that I can use the result in Outlook as `strBCC = strEmail`

```
Private Sub Command610_Click()
    Dim strEmail

    SELECT Member.HomeEmail
    FROM Member INNER JOIN MemberRole ON Member.MemberID = MemberRole.MemberID
    WHERE (((MemberRole.RoleID)=1) AND ((Member.ConstituencyPrefix)="DF") AND ((MemberRole.FinishDate) Is Null))
    ORDER BY Member.Surname;
End Sub
```

Help is more then welcome. I don't really know how to run a query in VBA; I tried `DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL`, but it's not the correct action.

I am almost there:

The variable strCons contains a number and I would like to add this to the SQL when I do this like below I get a run-time error '3061' Too few parameters. Expexted 1. Tried to find out why with no luck.

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset Dim strEmailTD As String

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Member.HomeEmail FROM Member INNER JOIN MemberRole ON Member.MemberID = MemberRole.MemberID WHERE ((**(MemberRole.AreaID)= strCons)** AND ((MemberRole.RoleID)=1) AND ((MemberRole.FinishDate) Is Null)) ORDER BY Member.Surname") strEmailTD = rs.Fields(0).Value rs.Close

Comment: How do you know it's not the correct action? Do you get an error? What does it say? It's not clear if you're asking whether your VBA is correct or simply how to run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign you *SQL* to a variable, and use this when opening a recordset:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim HomeEmail As String

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL) ' Your SQL.
HomeEmail = rs.Fields(0).Value
rs.Close
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav got it all most